# Rails /lib use in fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, module, fixtures

I have some common code that I have abstracted to a module in my `/lib` directory:

```
module ExampleModule
  
  def self.do_something
    # return a value
  end
end
```

I need to use this method in my test fixtures, however I am getting the following error when I run tests:

> Error:
>
> SomeTest#test_that_something:
>
> NoMethodError: undefined method `do_something' for ExampleModule:Module
> test/fixtures/model_name.yml:4:in `get_binding'

How can I access this method in the test fixtures? I can fix the error by requiring the module in other parts of the app that are loaded during test, but how would I require this module if it was needed specifically in the fixture file here? Would I need to require it in any test using the fixture?

Comment: Have you ensured that this isn't caused by some kind of slop error? It makes no sense that you would find the constant but not the method.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "slop error"? A mistyped method name? The method name has been repeatedly typed with both IDE autocompletion and copy-and-paste from the source to confirm that it is correct, and it works with no changes when the `require` is added to relevant test files.

Comment: Thats pretty much exactly it. Any kind of human error that cannot be reproduced such as errors due to unsaved files or source control.

Comment: In that case, yes, I checked that this was not the cause.